# Data Table request unknown parameter '0' from the data source for row 0

Tags: php, json, datatables

This is sample of my json response code :

```
[{"data":"{\"time\": \"2017-12-12 11:17:48\", \"user\": \"firman\", \"owner\": \"admin\", \"host_ip\": \"127.0.0.1\", \"user_ip\": \"192.168.3.235\", \"nas_port\": \"2162163717\", \"log_status\": \"accounting-success\", \"nas_port_id\": \"ether3-Hotspot\", \"nas_port_type\": \"wireless-802.11\", \"calling_station_id\": \"58:44:98:A0:A4:88\"}"},{"data":"{\"time\": \"2017-12-12 11:57:07\", \"user\": \"lenovo\", \"owner\": \"admin\", \"host_ip\": \"127.0.0.1\", \"user_ip\": \"192.168.3.236\", \"nas_port\": \"2162163713\", \"log_status\": \"accounting-success\", \"nas_port_id\": \"ether3-Hotspot\", \"nas_port_type\": \"wireless-802.11\", \"calling_station_id\": \"64:DB:43:BB:52:CF\"}"},{"data":"{\"time\": \"2017-12-12 04:59:19\", \"user\": \"endigo\", \"owner\": \"admin\", \"host_ip\": \"127.0.0.1\", \"user_ip\": \"192.168.3.240\", \"nas_port\": \"2160066562\", \"log_status\": \"accounting-success\", \"nas_port_id\": \"ether3-Hotspot\", \"nas_port_type\": \"wireless-802.11\", \"calling_station_id\": \"02:40:20:8F:F7:C0\"}"}]
```

When i load page ,  request unknown parameter '0' from the data source for row 0 show ,

And This is my datatable code :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#radius_log").DataTable({
fixedColumns: true,
fixedHeader: true,
"pageLength": 10,
"paging": true,
"ajax": {
    url: "./all_log",
    type: "GET",
    dataSrc: ""
},
"scrollX": true,
"columns": [
    {"data": "owner", "title": "Owner"},
    {"data": "user", "title": "User"},
    {"data": "user_ip", "title": "IP Address"},
    {"data": "host_ip", "title": "Radius Server"},
    {"data": "nas_port_id", "title": "NAS Port"},
    {"data": "nas_port_type", "title": "NAS Port Type"},
    {"data": "time", "title": "Time"}
    ]
     });
    </script>
```

Comment: Your JSON is invalid. You shouldn't need to escape quotes and you are placing all of your data into a string ("{"time":....

Comment: i have tried to validate json in jsonlint , it's truly valid .

Comment: @jeff is right, the problem is that the `data` items consist of strings, not valid JSON. The content of `data` must be parsed or the backend should deliver valid JSON.

Answer (score 1):

What your JSON is returning is:

[image]

What you want is:

[image]

Comment: You should explain how OP convert the "bad" strings to valid JSON.

Answer (score 0):

Having had a fiddle would have made it easier, so here is one: https://jsfiddle.net/g5fa1mo0/

I actually got 2 error-messages, the second one was very clear and pointed out that `owner`was missing from the first record!

Comment: Yes, every attributes is missing. DT does only alert for the very first record (1.234 alerts would be annoying, and turning alerts off is really not an option :).